# What are nivcsw and nvcsw fields in task_struct?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am studying about processes in Linux. I have a task to find some fields of PCB for a given process id in a kernel module. I found [this link](https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/structtask__struct.html#a6f8e491cf1d80eb127fe0c10ebbfc659) about `task_struct` and I almost did the task, but I still don't know what are the fields [`nivcsw`](https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/structtask__struct.html#a55f25b73a0d036f879fdd100686f0d45) and [`nvcsw`](https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/structtask__struct.html#a629c7251551c7da376f6e35c117fd92d). What do they store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `nvcsw` and `nivcsw` are [context switch counters](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.2.1/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1028). The first one represents the number of voluntary context switches (**N**umber of **V**oluntary **C**ontext **Sw**itches) while the second represents the number of involuntary context switches (**N**umber of **I**n**V**oluntary **C**ontext **Sw**itches).